# How to aggregate characters strings by group in R?

Tags: r, text, aggregation-framework, character

I have a web scraping data frame with different elements from some documents. I need to aggregate by the frist column, cause it identifies the document. Other columns are the kinds of elements from the text, with a lot of NA values. I want aggregate to make a row for each document with all elements.
I've this:

| DocID | ElementA | ElementB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | NA |
| 1 | NA | B1 |
| 2 | A2 | NA |
| 2 | NA | B2 |
| 3 | A3 | NA |
| 3 | NA | B3 |

And I want to get:

| DocID | ElementA | ElementB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to group by 'DocID', `fill` the columns 'ElementA', 'ElementB' with adjacent non-NA elements and get the `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(DocID) %>%
   fill(ElementA, ElementB, .direction = "downup") %>%
   ungroup %>%
   distinct
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  DocID ElementA ElementB
#  <int> <chr>    <chr>   
#1     1 A1       B1      
#2     2 A2       B2      
#3     3 A3       B3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(DocID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), ElementA = c("A1", 
NA, "A2", NA, "A3", NA), ElementB = c(NA, "B1", NA, "B2", NA, 
"B3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```